# Initialize child entry in destination collection prior to mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to utilize automapper for some conversions between two classes.

I have four classes - two parent classes where both have a child collection of the remaining two.

```
public class ParentA
{
    public IEnumerable<ChildA> Children{get;set;}
}

public class ChildA
{
    public ParentA Parent{get;set;
}

public class ParentB
{
    public IEnumerable<ChildA> Children{get;set;}
}

public class ChildB
{
    public ParentA Parent{get;set;
}
```

I need to ensure that the `Parent` property is set for both collections before mapping occurs. For the source object I do the following:

```
CreateMap<ParentA, ParentB>()
    .BeforeMap((a, b) =>
    {
        foreach (var entry in a.Entries)
            entry.Parent = a;
    })
```

However, I do not know how to do the same for the destination object. I need to check the parent due to some conditional mapping and value resolution.

Comment: The first parameter should be called source and the second destination.